# How to stop vim from creating log files

Tags: vim

Every time I open vim, it generates various log files.

```
bt_regexp_debug.log
bt_regexp_log.log
nfa_regexp_debug.log
nfa_regexp_dump.log
nfa_regexp_run.log
```

Why do they get created, and how can I get read of them?

Comment: How do you "open" it?  Any switches (options)?

Comment: In the most basic ways. No, Just by opening a file (`vim somefile`), or even `vim` alone generates this log files after exiting vim.

Comment: Are  you familiar with the `.vimrc` file -- have you customized it?

Comment: yes. I thought of it too, so I completely deleted it, and still got the same log files.

Comment: Heh. What is in them?   General start up messages? Loaded modules? ...

Comment: Any other configuration, perhaps in `.vim/` directory?  There has to be _some_ option somewhere that is setting it off to write that. This is not default behavior.

Comment: Other files that are suspect are `.exrc` and system-wide config, often `/etc/vimrc`.  Also: `vim` respects a `.vimrc` file in the directory in which it is started, if there is one there.

Comment: As, you can see by the answer below it was because I had compiled `vim` in `DEBUG` mode. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `regexp_nfa.c`:

```
#ifdef ENABLE_LOG
    log_fd = fopen(NFA_REGEXP_RUN_LOG, "a");

[...]

#ifdef ENABLE_LOG
    { 
        FILE *f = fopen(NFA_REGEXP_RUN_LOG, "a");
```

and from `regexp.c`:

```
#ifdef BT_REGEXP_LOG
    f = fopen("bt_regexp_log.log", "a");
```

All the calls to this seem to be wrapped in either a `#ifdef ENABLE_LOG` or `#ifdef BT_REGEXP_LOG`. On other words: they're compile-time switches.

Looking at the top of these two files, I see:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
# define NFA_REGEXP_ERROR_LOG   "nfa_regexp_error.log"
```

and:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
/* show/save debugging data when BT engine is used */
# define BT_REGEXP_DUMP
```

**Conclusion**: Your Vim is compiled with `DEBUG` defined.

You can verify this with `vim --version`, where it should show `DEBUG BUILD` at the bottom. I don't see any way to disable creating these files at runtime; you'll need to recompile Vim.

There doesn't seem to be a `configure` switch to enable/disable this. It should be disabled by default. In `feature.h` I see:

```
/*
 * DEBUG                Output a lot of debugging garbage.
 */
/* #define DEBUG */
```

And in `Makefile` I see:

```
#CFLAGS = -g -DDEBUG -Wall -Wshadow -Wmissing-prototypes
```

Note that both are commented out.

It's also possible you manually ran make with `make CFLAGS="-DDEBUG"`.

---

P.S. I didn't know any of this either, but quickly found the answer by using `grep` on the Vim source tree. Learn to love `grep`. `grep` is your friend. ;-)

Comment: Thank you! It was it! I would follow your advice and learn to love `grep`

Comment: @CamiloCelisGuzman `grep` is actually not such a great tool as such, by the way. I used it more in the generic "to search" meaning ;-) It doesn't really matter *which* tool you use, but I've often found that when encountered with a mysterious error, just searching for the error (or filename in this case) is a great way to find out where it comes from :-) If you want a command-line tool, then `grep` is always available and learning the basics is probably worth-while, but I find that [the_silver_searcher](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) is much better/faster tool in general...